# How to pass generic parameters to multiple delegates. 2 Delegates with generic parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a method which accepts two `delegate`s as parameters.

```
method1(Delegate delegate1,Delegate delegate2,params Object[] parameters)
{
    // There is lot of other code, I haven't put here. To make it clear.
    string key = delegate1.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
    object instance = delegate2.DynamicInvoke(parameters); 
    // Getting errors here, as parameters mismatch.
}

// Code from the Calling class
// There are many other classes in my project, which are calling Method1, 
// but the number of parameters of method2 and method3 always vary. 
private string Method2(object[] paramsObject)
{
    string key = string.Empty;
    foreach (object obj in paramsObject)
    {
        key += obj.ToString() + "|";
    }
    return key.Trim(new char[]{'|'});
}

private object Method3(object[] paramsObject)
{
    object object1 = paramsObject[0];
    object object2 = paramsObject[1];
    object object3 = paramsObject[2];
    object object4 = GetObjectUsingParameters(object1,object2,object3);
    return object4;
}


Func<string, string, string> Method2Delegate = Method2;
Func<object1,object2,object3,object4> Method3Delegate = Method3;
//Calling Method1
Method1(Method2Delegate,Method3Delegate,string str1,string str2,object object1,Object object2,Object object3);
```

I am getting an error in `Method1` when invoking the `delegate`s, parameters mismatch error.

As we can have only one one params parameter as input for a method at the end.

Could you please let me know, how can I bind the parameters to the same `delegate` or how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: why are you using DynamicInvoke instead of make it type save?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a delegate with the next signature:

```
delegate void MyCustomDelegate (params object[] params);
```

And then to define Method2Delegate and Method3Delegate as MyCustomDelegate type.

Comment: If i declare a delegate like this , Could you please let me know, how can I pass the parameters from the calling method? Or How the calling code should be?

Answer (score 0):

what about doing it like this:

```
method1(Func<object[],string> delegate1,Func<object[], object> delegate2,params Object[] parameters)
{

// There is lot of other code, I haven't put here. To make it clear.

    string key = delegate1(parameters);

    object instance = delegate2(parameters); 
// Getting errors here, as parameters mismatch. 

}
```

and at the caller just

```
Method1(Method2,Method3,string str1,string str2,object object1,Object object2,Object object3);
```

this way you don't need to define delegates that dynamically invoked.

Comment: Could you please let me know, how can I know in Method1 that str1,str2 are the parameters used by Method2 and Object1, Object2, Object3 are the parameters used by Method3?

Comment: you want to use the strings in method2 and the objects in method3?